# how to prove the following integral equality?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

$X$ is a r.v. which has pdf $f(x)$ and cdf $F(x)$

I want to  prove that:
$$\int_{a<x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_n<b}f(x_1)\cdots f(x_n)\,dx_1\cdots\,dx_n=\frac{1}{n!}(F(b)-F(a))^n$$

perhaps this question has been asked before but I can't fint it.

I have no idea why $n!$ appears in the rhs, maybe we can change the variables and $n!$ derives from the Jacobian, could you give me some hints?

Comment: Hint: try induction in n

Comment: The product of the $f(x_k)$ is the joint pdf of $n$ independent copies ofr the random var $X$ so without the order restriction you have $P(a<X<b)=F(b)-F(a),$ and then that to the $n$th gives prob that product of the n copies of X is between $a$ and $b.$ Since each ordering is equally likely, what follows?

Comment: @coffeemath thanks, I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n=2$,
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int_{a<x_1<x_2<b}f(x_1)f(x_2)dx_1dx_2\\
&=&\int_a^bf(x_1)\int^{x_1}_af(x_2)dx_2dx_1\\
&=&\int_a^bf(x_1)(F(x_1)-F(a))dx_1\\
&=&\frac{1}{2}(F(b)-F(a))^2.
\end{eqnarray}
Here $F'(x)=f(x)$. For $n>2$, you can use the Induction to do similarly.